# Validating data in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-security

I have a simple data node of users which looks something like this:

```
"users" : {
  "firebase_auth_uid" : {
   "avatarUrl" : "https://graph.facebook.com/.....",
   "name" : "Full Name",
   "registrationTimestamp" : longTimestamp
  }
}
```

And the rules for the above section as follows:

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "$uid == auth.uid",
    "registrationTimestamp":{
      ".validate": "!data.exists()"
    }
  }
}
```

As of my understanding of Firebase validation rules, this should allow the timestamp to be updated only when "registrationTimestamp" holds no data.

But all calls to `currentUser.child("registrationTimestamp").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);` overwrite the value of "registrationTimestamp".

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What version of Firebase are you running?  When I run your example on 9.0.2, I get "Permission denied" when data exists.

Comment: The only reason I could imagine this write seemingly going through is if you're not connected to the database. In that case, the local client (which doesn't enforce the rules) will surface the changes locally, before sending the data off to the servers. Once your reconnected to the database, that will validate and reject the write and you'll get a local write operation to reconcile.

Comment: @qbix  I am using _firebase-core:9.0.2_, I too get permission denied while recreating the scenario in the simulator but the android client successfully rewrites the value at the node.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no the project isn't deployed yet it's in development phase hence I can assure that the device is connected and the server does accepts the new timestamp